# when run the application the browser saying this is not available

Tags: php, netbeans

I try to create a new php project in netbeans but an error comes up saying "PHP Interpreter must be selected". I tried pointing it to my php.exe file found in my wamp directory "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe" but still nothing... any ideas? I attached where the error shows (in the options window
when running application its giving error "the webpage is not available)im unable to find the reason let me know how to solve this issue

Comment: did u give the file extension as `.php`

Comment: c:\wamp\bin\php\php.exe

Comment: @annam yes i given .php extension

Comment: @siva yes i set the c:\wamp\bin\php\php.exe as interpreter

Comment: once go through this page and check if you missed any...

`https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Just change the path to `c:\wamp\bin\php\php.exe` and check.

Comment: where is the location of your project folder. It should be in webroot directory.